# MATLAB array indexing error?

Tags: matlab

I have been doing array indexing as follows

```
>> n=[1 2 3]
n =
     1     2     3

>> idx=1
idx =
     1

>> n([idx+1 idx])
ans =
     2     1
```

**without any problem.** However, today I encounter this error in my following snippet. Please forgive me. I understand I should provide MWE, but I simply cannot reproduce the error!

```
>> %%% interpret tree
bitmap = zeros(pix_no_per_side, pix_no_per_side);
x_pixels = 1:1:pix_no_per_side;
y_pixels = 1:1:pix_no_per_side;
rule_set = {}; % cell to accommodate rows of diff. sizes
% parse branches
trav_iter = tr.depthfirstiterator;
while tr.get(trav_iter(end)) <= 0 % still have branch unparsed
    branch = [1]; % contains the root
    node_idx = 1;
    while tr.get(branch(end)) > 0 % not bottom yet
        node_idx = node_idx+1;
        branch = [branch trav_iter(node_idx)];
    end
    rule_set{end+1} = branch; % one rule per cell
    disp(node_idx) % DISPLAYING FOR DEBUGGING
    if numel(rule_set) == 1 % only one branch found so far
        trav_iter(node_idx) = []; % remove this leaf
    else % more than one branches found so far
        trav_iter([node_idx-1 node_idx]) = []; % remove this leaf and parent node
    end
end
     3

     3

     2

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that error message is triggered by

```
trav_iter(end)
```

where `trav_iter` is possibly to be empty.

Reproducing the error then becomes.

```
>> a = []

a =

     []

>> a(end)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Hence, to fix that, I add one logical and to make sure that the `trav_iter` is not empty. i.e.,

```
while numel(trav_iter) ~= 0 && tr.get(trav_iter(end)) <= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The index `node_idx-1` is likely either `0` or `-1`.  The subscript error almost always indicates this problem.  However, any empty, `NaN` or other value can cause this as well.

Perhaps this is because the assignment `node_idx = 1;` sets the value and in your last loop, it is never incremented yielding a `0` index.

Comment: Thanks, but the `3 3 2` is what I get when I do `disp(node_idx)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your debugging line is that it only displays the output of `node_idx` at the end of the while loop.  If it errors after setting `node_idx` to 1 and before hitting `disp` then you will not see the value of the index that caused the error.

Here's a simple way of understanding it:

```
x = 1:3

for n = 3:-1:0
    y = x(n);
    disp(n)
end
```

As you can probably guess, the above code will error when `n` gets to 0, 
However, when it runs, I get:

```
     3

     2

     1

Attempted to access x(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.
```

i.e. `disp` never shows `0`.

But from the command line:

```
>> n

n =

     0
```

If this is within a function, use `dbstop if error` and then check `node_idx` when the code stops.